# ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at WebIntent.get [as ACTION_VIEW]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to integrate Google pay into my app using `web intent plugin`. After I completed the install I got the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at WebIntent.get [as
>   ACTION_VIEW]

[Click here for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljeh7.png)